# What is the derivate of $A \cdot\cos{ (B\cdot (x + C))} - D$?

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

$$f(x) = A \cdot \cos{(B\cdot(x+C))} - D$$
$$f'(x) = \text{ ?}$$

I would assume that the derivate is something like this:

$$f'(x) = - A \cdot B \cdot \sin{( \dots )}$$

The thing that troubles me is the inside of the cosine function. The $B$ will stay as it is, but what happens to the $C$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The argument stays the same, the rest is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x) = A\cos (B (x + C)) - D$$
$$f'(x) = (A\cos (B (x + C)) - D)'$$
$$= (A\cos (B (x + C)))' - D'$$
$$= A(\cos (B (x + C)))' - 0$$
$$= A(\cos (B (x + C))'(B(x+C))'$$
$$=A(-\sin(B(x+C))\cdot B$$
$$=-AB\sin(B(x+C))$$

Comment: Cheers mate! :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it all at once. If you were asked to compute

$$ 17 \cos(5 (3\pi + \pi))$$

you wouldn't start by trying to write down the answer. You would first compute $3 \pi + \pi = 4 \pi$, and then $5 (4 \pi) = 20 \pi$, and so forth.

It's the same deal with derivatives: you work through them one piece at a time. The derivative rules are often even presented in a way to make it evident how to do this, but you can always use the chain rule when they're not.

For example, the derivative of

$$ \cos u$$

is

$$ (-1) u' \sin u $$

If you have trouble working it out, it helps to actually define variables and make substitutions to make things easier.

I.E. don't try to find the derviative of

$$ A \cdot \cos{(B\cdot(x+C))} - D $$

Instead, define the variables

$$ v = A \cdot \cos{(B\cdot(x+C))} $$
$$ w = D $$

then compute the derivative of

$$ v - w $$

This will, for example, involve computing $v'$. Repeat the same idea to help organize your work when trying to compute the derivative of $v$.

It's possible to work from the inside out as well. Start by defining

$$ u = x + C$$

and find the derivative $u'$. Then, define

$$ v = B u $$

and compute the derivative $v'$. Then define

$$ w = \cos v $$

and compute $w'$, and so forth. This approach may be more intuitive, since you work through the expression in exactly the same way as if everything was a number and you were just trying to compute a decimal value.